# Add a first value to spinner when spinner data is came from server

Tags: java, android, arraylist, spinner

I want to set first spinner value as  "select your choice" then shows the data from server
one solution

- creates another array list and in that list contain the value "select your choice" and
  combine these two and set to the spinner ..
  how can I achieve this please help me... (using cursor ????)

  ```
  Spinner spinner;
  private JSONArray result;
  ArrayList<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
  spinner.setPrompt("...Select the Vehicle Number...");

  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
  {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String vno = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }
  ```

method for getting spinner data

```
JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Spinner value");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject job = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = job.getString("spinner_data");
    allNames.add(name);

}

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, allNames);


spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: What is error log?

Comment: allNames.add("Select Name"); add this line before for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add String **-Select Your Choice-**  as the first element in the array List.

```
 String choice1 =  "-Select Your Choice-";
 allNames.add(choice1);     
 JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Spinner value");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject job = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = job.getString("spinner_data");
                    allNames.add(name);

                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                        (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, allNames);


                spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Spinner value");
 allNames.add("Select Your Choice");    
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject job = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = job.getString("spinner_data");
    allNames.add(name);

 }

 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
 (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, allNames);


 spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  allNames.clear();
  allNames.add("Select Vehicle");
  JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Spinner value");
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
  {
  JSONObject job = array.getJSONObject(i);
  String name = job.getString("spinner_data");
  allNames.add(name);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this,

```
allNames.add("select your choice")

JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Spinner value");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
JSONObject job = array.getJSONObject(i);
String name = job.getString("spinner_data");
allNames.add(name);}
```

It will automatically set first index as choice option.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `object` similar to the `response` received from server and add it to your `list` before parsing server data.

As here your server response is only string you can add a string object to your list.

```
allNames.clear();
allNames.add("Your First Option");//any string that relevance to your need
//code to parse server response
allNames.add(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,
Before calling getting spinner data method, just add this line

```
String name="select your choice"
allNames.add(name);
```

then initialize getting spinner data form server

Answer (score 0):

```
String choice1 =  "Select Your Choice";
 allNames.add(choice1);  


JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Spinner value");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject job = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = job.getString("spinner_data");
                    allNames.add(name);

                }
```

Comment: what is Ws responce

Comment: its your parsed json object list of string.

Comment: in my case what is responce list